# Variables in jinja2 template imported by flask duplicated

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I try to use Flask to scan all the file in a specific folder and build the url links to those files automatically, so first I defined a app route in Flask:

```
homepath = os.getcwd()    # the root path of the app
@app.route('/<folder>/')          
def showList(folder):
    folder_abs_path = homepath + '/static/'+folder
    files = os.listdir(folder_abs_path)
    return render_template('blog_list.html', files=files, folderName=folder)
```

And create a jinja2 template like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div id="main-contents">
  <ul>  
    {% for item in files %}
    <li><a href="{{ folderName +'/'+ item }}"> {{ item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When flask is running,I typed:

```
http://localhost:5000/test/
```

it does work, list all the files in my test folder(which is "file1.md" and "file2.md"), but it doesn't ceate the proper url links for the files, when I clicked the file1.md in the local web page, it directed to a url like:

```
http://localhost:5000/test/test/file1.md
```

What I want is "http://localhost:5000/test/file1.md", so why there two "test" folder name?

Comment: You are generating a relative path, you have to make it absolute. see the generated source.

Comment: Because the url will be sent to the server as the GET message, so it can't be absolute path, or do you have any solutions about that, currently I manually add the folder name in the template.

Answer (score 0):

As @Klaus said in the comment, you are generating relative paths for the static files. To avoid that, just use the [url_for()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for) function in the template for path generating:

```
{% extends "layouts/main.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="main-contents">
  <ul>  
    {% for item in files %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('static', filename=folderName + '/' + item)}}"> {{ item }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: For  your solution, the url it generated will be "http://localhost:5000/static/test/file1.md", and it will redirected to the orignal file, not the GET request I want send to the server. 

I currently avoid the problem by use different template for different folder.

Comment: Then what is your goal exactly? Sending a request to `test/file1.md` does nothing at the moment.